# Azure artifacts - How to add additional Maven repositories as upstream

Tags: java, maven, apache-phoenix, azure-artifacts

I am starting to use Azure artifacts from Azure DevOps services as Maven repository for our Java projects. We have an application with following dependency for which build is failing as the dependency is not resolved.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.7.2.8.5-5</version>
</dependency>
```

This artifact is located at Cloudera repository (https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/)

I am not finding a way to add a new Maven upstream in Azure artifacts. Documentation says it supports certain upstream maven repositories only.

I also tried with following version of the dependency, which available in maven central

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-HBase-2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Version 5.0.0-HBase-2.0 also resulted in error with following error

```
Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-core:jar:5.0.0-HBase-2.0 -> org.apache.hbase:hbase-mapreduce:jar:2.0.0 -> org.apache.hbase:hbase-server:jar:2.0.0 -> org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp:jar:2.3.2 -> org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish:javax.el:pom:3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots, default, snapshots)]
```

Any suggestions to circumvent this?

Comment: Why not add the Cloudera repository as additional `<repository>` to your `settings.xml`? Or otherwise, add it to Azure DevOps, if possible.

Comment: I am looking for ways to add Cloudera repository as an upstream repository to Azure Artifacts (which is the Maven repository in Azure DevOps). From the Azure DevOps portal, there is an option to add new upstream but only allows npm repositories not Maven repositories.

Comment: According to Microsoft support, Azure Artifacts support Maven Central, Google Maven Repository, Gradle Plugins, and JitPack as upstream sources for Maven. So as suggested added additional <repository> to get the build working.